# How to know why a program won't start?

Tags: windows-vista

I have machine running Windows Vista and I would like to test this program: [Graph Magics](http://www.graph-magics.com/download.php). It doesn't claim to be compatible with Windows Vista, so I'm not completely surprised that it doesn't work. It just does nothing and fails to run silently. I tried the XP compatibility mode with no success.

Is there a way to know why it won't start ?

Comment: maybe you can find an entry in the eventlog?

Comment: Run `compmgmt.msc` and look through system and application logs. You may also try running it as Administrator.

Comment: The explanation may be there but I can't find it. Is there a way to export this as a file and grep through it ?

Comment: have you installed the .Net Framework 1.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A useful tool for such diagnostic is [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), which can report a failed attempt to read (or write) a file or a registry key.

But it might need some programming knowledge to fully understand the output...